# How can chagnge bg color of checked input checkout box in bootstrap 5? i m using angular 12

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I m trying to change background color of the input checkbox 'when checked' in bootstrap 5, I even found some solutions for custom bootstrap checkbox but it is also not working,any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

```css
/*Default Checkbox*/

.form-check .form-check-input:checked~.form-check-label::before {
  background-color: green!important;
}

.form-check .form-check-input:checked:focus~.form-check-label::before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(220, 7, 7), 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25)
}

.form-check .form-check-input:focus~.form-check-label::before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(31, 161, 175), 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)
}

.form-check .form-check-input:active~.form-check-label::before {
  background-color: #e112cc;
}


/*Custom Checkbox*/

.custom-control-label:before {
  background-color: red;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::before {
  background-color: black;
}

.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:checked~.custom-control-label::after {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath fill='red' d='M6.564.75l-3.59 3.612-1.538-1.55L0 4.26 2.974 7.25 8 2.193z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.custom-control-input:active~.custom-control-label::before {
  background-color: green;
}


/** focus shadow pinkish **/

.custom-checkbox .custom-control-input:focus~.custom-control-label::before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #fff, 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255, 0, 247, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Default checkbox</label>
</div>
<div class="myTest custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">Check this custom checkbox</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The checkbox styling is derived from the browser engine and cannot be edited with css.

You will, as you noted, need to make a custom checkbox.

Here is an example:

```css
.form-check {
  position: relative;
}

[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

[type=checkbox]+label {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

[type=checkbox]+label::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 2px;
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border: 2px solid #8f8f9d;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

[type=checkbox]:checked+label::before {
  content: "✔";
  background: green;
  border-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 11px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-check">
  <input type="checkbox" id="flexCheckDefault">
  <label for="flexCheckDefault">Default checkbox</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code sir, but when i convert it in jspdf then it is showing only green color in checkbox, tick sign not showing.

Comment: @manojsahni That would be a seperate issue that you should raise as a new query. I suspect it it likely an issue with unicode support in jspdf. You could try adding an X instead of a tick to see if it displays after conversion.

Comment: Yes, you are right X and other alphabet character is working, but I didn't understand why check symbol is not printing, can you help me on this

Comment: When using print to PDF the font is usually included within the conversion script. So non standard characters (e.g unicode symbols) are not being included in the PDF font. To utilise this you would need to either 1. include the unicode tick character in the conversion font. (would mean editing the scipt) 2. Use a character that is included. (Try some charmap characters). 4 Switch to using an image instead. 4. Use a differant PDF convertor.

Comment: Thank you, sir, for your support it will help for my improvement .